# Confusion about creating and writing to File in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a new file and then write some content to it just to create a basic backup of a template.

When I log out the values of `filename` and `file_content` they are correct, but when I send the data all I get is a file named after the method (`download_include`) and a fixnum inside the file, the last one made was `15`.

```
  # POST /download_include/:id
  def download_include
    @include = Include.find(params[:id])
    version_to_download = @include.latest_version_record
    filename = "#{version_to_download.name}"
    file_content = "#{version_to_download.liquid_code.to_s}"

    file = File.open(filename, "w") { |f| f.write (file_content) }

    send_data file
  end
```

I also tried `send_file` but that produces the error

```
no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

I also tried to just write dummy values like below, and it still produced a file named after the method with a fixnum inside it.

```
file = File.open("DOES THIS CHANGE THE FILENAME?", "w") { |f| f.write ("FILE CONTENT?") }
```

I feel I am missing something obvious but I cannot figure it out after looking at many examples here and in blogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't end along the filename as an option for send_data, it defaults to the method name.

Secondly, the download wants to read the data from a buffer.  My guess is your syntax is just sending a file handle.

Try this...

`send_data(file.read, filename: filename)`

Or skip the intermediate file and try...

`send_data(version_to_download.liquid_code.to_s, filename: filename)`

Comment: I knew it was something like that, thanks so much for your help

Comment: Actually I was wrong - Rails calls to `.to_s` on whatever you pass and does not actually stream it.